# What is the scope of Electronics Engineering in Robotics/Automation?

Tags: robotics

I am beginner in Robotics .I have taken admission for Electronics engineering one year back as we hardly have specifically Robotics Engineering Branch in my Country.Now,I am suffering from questions like what is the scope of Electronics( **not Electrical**) Engineering in Robotics/ Automation?
**Also,if I don't like to do programming ,are there other options to stick to Robotics / Automation field as per my branch(Electronics Engineering ) is concerned (i.e.. Where should I give focus?)**.

Comment: For hardware in this day and age, learn to like programming. Early in my career I did mainly hardware design and it was a struggle testing designs that required programming. I had to rely on other people to provide test software and to get the configurations right ... very frustrating. Now days I do most of the necessary programming myself, but for my designs that are programmed by others I provide working configurations, drivers and sample code for all the peripherals. As a bonus, there is very little finger-pointing about whether something is a hardware or software problem.

Comment: @ Andy aka sir,what changes should I do in my question?

Comment: @Tut sir,then from which Programming language and hardware basics should I start with  ?

Comment: That is a very broad question in itself. I prefer C, but I'm the wrong person to ask about modern languages and trends for the future. As far as hardware, my personal interests lie in Electronics Engineering; but for Robotics there are many needs, for example Computer Science and Mechanical Engineering. Perhaps you should see what is taught in schools offering a Robotics curriculum? One other point, try not to be too narrowly focused, things change and you never know what the future will bring.

Comment: @Ricardo sir, what changes should I do in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't like programming, but you want to do Robotics?  You're on to a real loser there then.

A huge amount of the work on robotics is done in programming to tell them what to do.  Mostly in the fields of Artificial Intelligence, object recognition, environment interaction, etc.

But of course robots wouldn't exist without electronics.  It's all very well being a whiz kid at programming, but if the robot doesn't have decent electronics it's not going to work.

It's best to think of a robot and its fields of engineering as a human body.

The human body has a brain. It has a skeleton and musculature. It has a nervous system.

The brain is the programming.  It's complex, it's powerful, it's an entire masters degree all to itself.

The skeleton and musculature is mechanical engineering.  Motors, actuators, solenoids, all that kind of thing.  How do you make a robotic hand actually move at a physical level.

Then there's the nervous system.  Connecting the brain to the muscles, nerve endings in the finger tips, optic nerves, eyeballs, all that kind of thing.  That's where the electronics come in to play.

No one part of that mix can exist without the rest. You can't have a robot without a body. You can't control the muscles without a brain. The brain can't tell the muscles what to do without a nervous system.  All fields are as important as each other and a good understanding of all three of them is important for a good understanding of robotics.

Of course, you can specialize, and it's good to specialize - especially if you are going to be part of a team. If you team up with programming specialists and with mechanical engineering specialists then all of you together can make a good team. But you still need to have some knowledge of the other fields.  You need to know how to interface your electronics to the brain, and how the brain is going to be talking to those electronics.  You need to know what kind of motors and sensors and feedback systems are going to be needed and how they will be manipulated by the robot as a whole.

So I'm sorry, but really you're going to have to suffer some programming, and some mechanical engineering, to complement your electronic engineering.

Typical things you would need to be concerned with in electronics for robotics though (others, please feel free to suggest more) are:

- Sensors
- Vision systems
- Motor driving - servos, stepper motors, BLDC, etc
- Signal conditioning
- Transmission and communication systems
- Computer interface technologies
- Power transmission and control
- EMI hardening
- Interlock systems

... and I'm sure there's more.  So pretty much the entire field of electronic engineering.

Comment: Sir,I am unable to distinguish between role of Software engineer and Electronics Engineer in Robotics.As in both cases,programming/coding is done.

Comment: The distinction is with what you do with the programming.  The software engineer writes the brain of the system - the understanding of what data comes in and how to react to it.  The electronic engineer programs the interface systems - microcontrollers etc to interface sensors with the "brain".

Comment: ok.sir,can u suggest which basic programming language should I learn for interfacing?

Comment: C or C++ are the most common ones.  Assembly language is good to know as well, even if you never really use it - it gives a good understanding of the underlying workings of the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

There is a type of robot they call [BEAM](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM_robotics). It doesn't use microprocessors or any programming but rather a feedback loop taking inputs from sensors to perform different tasks.   It's supposed to be based on biology, like the way an ant function.  I've mainly seen it used in toys but the concept is interesting.  I've also seen it used in what's called rider and horse, where the body or motion section is designed with this technique,  but the brains to decide where to go is a more traditional mcu.   In any case I've always thought it was interesting.   On the other hand it can't hurt to learn a little programming...